# Why synchronize on small objects?

Tags: java, synchronization

How does synchronization block in Java performance depends on object size on which synchronization is being performed?

```
synchorized (lock) {
    //some code here
}
```

Imagine lock could be just `new Object()` as it is used to be or it could be instance of immutable class but with a huge number of fields initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`synchronized` is not affected by the object size as it is a (small) semaphore on the object, the performance issues are related to how multiple threads access the object, in other words, on how the application is architected.

Comment: `synchorized is not affected by the object size..` +1

Answer (score 0):

The synchronization's performance does not depend on the size of the object you're synchronizing on. However, using a "large" object for synchronization may hurt performance in other areas - first, it may take time to initialize it, and second, it will hog memory, causing more page-faults etc. (assuming it's not required by your code regardless, in which case it makes no sense to hold an **additional** object just for synchronization purposes).